# json_normalize nested json object inside CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, azure, csv

I'm working on a script that calls our Azure Cost Management endpoint to retrieve utilization metrics.  The payload is returned as a csv and all the columns are neatly aligned, except for our internal resource tags we use in Azure.

Those come back as a nested json inside the csv column.  I've been trying to use json_normalize to flatten the Tags column but have not had much luck.  Below is a row example of the data source (green markup is my aspiration for flattening the json inside the csv):

[image]

I've tried a number of methods found here on stack and from other sources online but keep hitting a dead end.

As an experiment, I took a single row and converted it into a json object:

```python
df = pd.read_csv('data_in/2020-04-06_azure.csv')
d1 = df[250:251]
d2 = d1.to_json(orient='split')
print(d2)
```

Which gives me this:

```json
{
  "columns": [
    "Service",
    "Category",
    "Date",
    "Cost",
    "Subscription",
    "ResourceGroup",
    "Tags",
    "Id"
  ],
  "index": [
    250
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "Azure",
      "Bandwidth",
      "2020-04-05",
      0.0000038429,
      "Production",
      "testclient-prod-rg",
      "{  \"Client\": \"Client A\",  \"Budget\": \"Research-and-Development\",  \"Description\": \"resource group for testclient storage account\",  \"Name\": \"filler\",  \"Owner\": \"some@email.com\"}",
      "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/testclient-prod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/ccsmtestclientdata"
    ]
  ]
}
```

If I run json_normalize against the above dataframe `print(json_normalize(d2))` it fails:  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

So I try and make an even more simple experiment... make a dataframe out of just one row example of the Tags column and just try to normalize a single instance:

```python
df = pd.read_csv('data_in/2020-04-06_azure.csv')
d1 = df[250:251]
d2 = d1['Tags']
print(d2)
```

```
Output:
250    {  "Client": "Test",  "Budget": "Research-and...
Name: Tags, dtype: object
```

Try and normalize the json

```python
print(json_normalize(d2))
```

```
Output:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

**EDIT:** per comments below, what I'd want to see from json_normalize would be something like:

```
Tags.Client | Tags.Budget | Tags.Blah | Tags.Etc
--------------------------------------------------
Client A    | Production  | Value Foo | Value Bar
```

I'm new to python, so apologies if this seems straight forward - I don't understand how there are no values inside the data frame.

Other approaches I've also tried is making an iterator using json.load and json.dumps to try and manipulate it.  I think my next step is to make a regex iterator to loop through the rows and extract / append each item in the tags field.

The challenging part is that the Tags JSON in the csv is not consistent - so some rows will have null, while another might have 'Client' and 'Budget' and still others might have 5 or 6 additional Tags used by our dev teams.

Comment: It would help to show what you want the output to look like, given the JSON snippet above in d2.

Comment: Similar to the picture posted in original post - flatten the json attributes to its own column label: Tags.client | Tags.budget | Tag.blah - and then fill the respective fields with the attribute in the nest json

Comment: can you print the type of the object? i suspect it's not a json or dictionary can you try `d2 = eval(d2)` then run `json_normalize()`

Comment: `d2 = eval(d2)` produces `TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`.

Comment: pass it into ```json.loads``` : ```extract = json.loads(content['data'][0][6])```. you can write a loop to pull out the others. the assumption here is that the dat u need is in the 6th index